# Think I have the right indexes and query, but MySQL Query is still slow

Tags: mysql, mariadb

`table_1`

```
id | column_1 | import_date
```

Indexes: Mutli-column key (`multi_column`) of `import_date` and `column_1` in addition to an individual index for each column.

`table_2`

```
id | column_1 | column_2
```

Indexes: Multi-column key (`multi_column`) for `column_1` and `column_2` in addition to an individual index for each column.

i.e. both tables have two composite indexes (of the same name in this question) as well as separate indexes.

**Query**

I've tried flipping the query around and playing with using/forcing different indexes but it didn't seem to help.

```
SELECT table_1.import_date, count(*) AS count
FROM table_1
FORCE INDEX (import_date)
JOIN table_2 USE INDEX (multi_column) ON table_1.column_1 = table_2.column_1 AND column_2 = "Some String"
WHERE table_1.import_date >= '2016-05-26'
GROUP BY table_1.import_date
LIMIT 365
```

I tried adding in the `LIMIT` and a where clause to check where the date was greater than the same date last year just to try and prevent a large number of results and filter but neither seemed to improve the performance of the query, both tables have a large record set.

**EXPLAIN**

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  table_1 NULL    range   multi_column,import_date    import_date 6   NULL    1932171 100.00  Using index condition; Using where
1   SIMPLE  table_2 NULL    ref multi_column    multi_column    126 table_1.column_1,const  117 100.00  Using index
```

Sorry for obfuscated table and column names, trying to keep it simple.

Original Explain without force/use:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  table_1 NULL    index   multi_column,column_1,import_date   import_date 69  NULL    365 100.00  Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  table_2 NULL    ref multi_column,column_1,column_2  multi_column    126 table_1.column_1,const  117 100.00  Using index
```

Row counts for each table are 3,937,236 and 4,503,551 respectively.

The query currently takes around 80s, how long should it take, I'm not sure but I imagined with indexes then hopefully under a second.

Running locally on my development machine just now, Mac OS X El Capitan, 2.2 GHz i7 16gb ram.

MySQL version 5.7.15

Both tables are using InnoDB.

This query seems to take it down to roughly 20 seconds:

```
select import_date, count(*) as count
from table_1
where exists (select * from table_2 where table_1.column_1 = table_2.column_1 and column_2 = 'Some String')
group by import_date
```

Comment: It would be simpler and more precise to provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` than try to explain the indexes in English.

Answer (score 1):

How about `FORCE INDEX (import_date)` to `FORCE INDEX (multi_column)`?

Comment: I think it was trying to use that index by default but the query seems to take too long regardless of the indexes I choose to use/force.

Comment: The original query uses index method and need to traverse rows less than force/use index, but the result seems not. Could you use optimize/analyze tables and test again?

Answer (score 1):

That `EXPLAIN` shoes that it is reading 1,932,171 rows from table_1 which explains it taking a long time. What is the query plan when you don't give index use hints?<sup>[1]</sup>.

<sup>[1] Add this extra info to your question, along with the extra detail others have suggested, rather than in a comment</sup>

You may be hitting the issue of it only being able to use one index per table, and needing to use two in this case to be efficient: one to filter on date and one to perform the `JOIN` operation efficiently. It may be helpful to the query planner to have an index that covers `import_date, column_1` instead of just `import_date`.

Comment: thanks David, just updated the question when you posted with original explain.

Answer (score 1):

**Slightly modified query**

```
SELECT  table_1.import_date, count(*) AS count
    FROM  table_1
    JOIN  table_2  ON table_1.column_1 = table_2.column_1
                 AND  table_2.column_2 = "Some String"
    WHERE     table_1.import_date >= '2016-05-26'
    GROUP BY  table_1.import_date
    ORDER BY  table_1.import_date
    LIMIT  365
```

Without an `ORDER BY`, you can't be sure which 365 rows you will get, so I added such.

**Analysis** *without the hints*.

- `table_1`: `INDEX(import_date)` will take care of the filtering, grouping, and sorting, thereby leading to only 365 rows of `table_1` needing to be touched.
- `INDEX(import_date, column_1)`, in *this* order, is an improvement on that by making it "covering".
- `table_2`: `INDEX(column_1, column_2)`, in *either* order, is then perfect for reaching `table_2`.  Furthermore, this index is "covering"
- `EXPLAIN` indicates "covering" by saying "Using index".
- "Using index condition" (alias ICP or Index Condition Pushdown) is a different optimization, often less useful.

Bottom line:  That *should* have been the best way to write the query.  Since it did not seem to be, let me ramble on about other possibilities.

**How much I/O**

If you are using InnoDB, what is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  For larger machines, it should be about 70% or RAM.

Rule of Thumb:  The data in a table or an index is stored in a BTree structure with about 100 'rows' per 16KB leaf-node block.

A Covering index will do all the work in the index.  For table_1, that is about 4 blocks to get the needed info.  table_2 is messier to compute.  It will probably involve 365 probes into the index, together with reading (and counting) some number of rows each.

You cannot get the query to run any faster other than with shrinking datatypes, adding RAM, using a Summary table, etc. -- various things that you cannot control from the indexes or the formulation of the query.

**Effect of LIMIT, etc**

Any of these can change the `EXPLAIN`.  Please focus on whatever matches your *real* query:

- `ORDER BY + LIMIT` leads to a significant optimization wherein it can avoid gathering all the data, then sorting.
- Adding columns to the `SELECT` -- This is likely to kill the "covering" that I am taking advantage of.  This can lead to a significant de-optimization.  It would have to bounce between the index BTree and the data BTree, usually more than doubling the work.
- If the filtering (`WHERE`) hits more than an estimated 20% of the table, the Optimizer will probably ignore the index and simply do a table scan (to avoid the bouncing).
- And many more.

**Fair timing**

I brought up the buffer_pool_size and the details of the operation, because it sounded like the timings you took may not have been using a "warm" cache.  Please run each query twice (with the Query cache turned off or bypassed); take the second timing.  It will give you a fair comparison.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the detailed answer. I've just checked and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is set to `134217728` which doesn't seem like very much but this is on my local machine.

Comment: Hence the tables are a lot bigger than the cache, so you are probably suffering from a lot of I/O.  My recommended formulation and indexes are probably the best medicine.

Comment: The query is performing an aggregate. I get that the limit is on the aggregate result, which means that (unless table_2. column_1 is `UNIQUE`, which diesn't seem to be necessary under this scenario) it will not just read 365 rows, but as many as needed. See an example *[here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a9fb127b764d386c1e623146a9a412f2)*

Comment: *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=71f1314fc3753cd7e1aded43b80ee060)* (added EXPLAIN)